# Image scroll effect ? Android

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, parallax, weather

i have tried to mimic the scroll effect for image like in Yahoo weather app while scrolling up and also for view pager  but not successful . has anyone tried similar thing ?

Comment: you mean swipe on a photo and change it?

Comment: yes, that scroll effect

Comment: look at the developers page and see how to detect the swipe and animation